# My son is 6 and goes to the bath room but doesnt like to wipe

Tags: discipline

he comes home from school soiled on his underwear and rashed really  bad. He doesnt care that kids make fun of him. I need help. Its happening every day.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! What have you tried with regards to rewards/bribes/consequences/etc.? Has anything worked for a short while (or longer)? The more details you can provide, the better the chances of a helpful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting enough I've had this same issue w a few children.  I have a question, how much attention are you giving this?  I mean in regards to how upset you are getting or if it's turned into a daily stressor that your son can expect as soon as he gets home.

Children this age don't care about the concept of friends like adults might.  They have no concept of this yet.  The do what they do to see what reactions it gets. It's that simple in their world.

I watched a little girl who was doing this.  What her parents and I started doing was reminding her each time she went to the bathroom to be sure to wipe well so she wouldn't get sore. We also went back to supervising her bathroom time.  Maybe see if his teacher will help with this.

Another suggestion, stop making a big deal out of it.  Honestly, if it's getting him this much attention, his plan is working lol.  So often when our children do something shocking or upsetting we get all wound up and make it into a big deal...which is usually what they're looking for.  Stop checking his underwear when he walks in the door, stop talking about it in front of him.

If necessary start treating it like beginner potty training. Without saying a word, go with him, help him wipe and clean up then move on.  Don't threaten him, bribe or harass him. Just start going with him and when he asks why, tell him. You want to make sure he's clean so you're helping.  Take away the focused attention of it.  He is only 6 and this isn't really unusual for his age. Be casual and calm about it like it's no big deal. From my experience very quickly they tend to get annoyed and will ask you to stop.  Then just casually ask if he's sure because you want to make sure he's clean and you just want to help.  Be clueless, like your talking about the weather or something simple.

Also keep in mind, wiping that back area can be an awkward reach for some kids.  He might be having issues with this or be in a rush.  I'm not big on suggesting bribes or rewards for things that should just be done.  Like wipe and I'll give you a sticker?  No, step in and just start helping him.  It's not going to hurt and you might find out the real reason for why he's not wanting to do it....like he can't reach or he's trying and not doing a good job.

Breathe, be patient, he's only 6...this is a little battle.  Best of luck!!

Comment: "Children this age don't care about the concept of friends like adults might." I am interested in seeing some evidence for this. They may not have the same deep understanding of friendships, but it doesn't mean they don't care much or that peer pressure doesn't exist for them. Also, the tone of this is fairly negative towards the OP. You don't know what is going on; that's what *comments asking for clarification* are for. Your first paragraph is just such a comment. Waiting for a response is always an option.